# Download Cortana schema definition

Tags: xml, xsd, cortana

How does one go about downloading the Cortana voicecommands xml schema definition? The url listed in the example projects I have found point to this url:

http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.1

However when I browse to that url, nothing is visible. Intellisense works for the xml document elments I create so I can only assume that it is able to load the schema from that url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my machine the file is located in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Xml\Schemas\1033

And in that location there are a number of files including

> WindowsPhoneVoiceCommandDefinition_v11.xsd

which is the schema definition file for the namespace
http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.1

Answer (score 1):

You can find useful information on [Voice Command Definition (VCD) elements and attributes v1.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722331.aspx)

Here's an example of a complete VCD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
  <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="HomeControlCommandSet_en-us">
    <CommandPrefix>HomeControl</CommandPrefix>
    <Example>Control alarm, temperature, light and others</Example>

    <Command Name="Activate_Alarm">
      <Example>Activate alarm</Example>
      <ListenFor>[Would] [you] [please] activate [the] alarm [please]</ListenFor>
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase">Activate alarm</ListenFor>
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="ExplicitlySpecified">Activate {builtin:AppName} alarm</ListenFor>
      <Feedback>Activating alarm</Feedback>
      <Navigate />
    </Command>

    <Command Name="Change_Temperature">
      <Example>Change temperature to 25º degrees</Example>
      <ListenFor>Change temperature to {temperature} degrees</ListenFor>
      <Feedback>Changing temperature to {temperature} degrees</Feedback>
      <Navigate />
    </Command>

    <Command Name="Change_Light_Color">
      <Example>Change light color to yellow</Example>
      <ListenFor>Change light color to {colors}</ListenFor>
      <Feedback>Changing light color to {colors}</Feedback>
      <Navigate />
    </Command>

    <PhraseList Label="colors">
      <Item>yellow</Item>
      <Item>green</Item>
      <Item>red</Item>
    </PhraseList>

    <PhraseTopic Label="temperature">
    </PhraseTopic>

  </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

For more information, please visit this link [http://talkitbr.com/2015/07/13/integrando-a-cortana-em-seu-aplicativo-windows-10](http://talkitbr.com/2015/07/13/integrando-a-cortana-em-seu-aplicativo-windows-10/)